# Crystal Reports Good Alternative

Tags: crystal-reports

I see there are already many posts asking for alternative, but no answer explain concretely why choose this or that solution...

I have tried Valentina Reports, that is very not comfortable at all. I explain here what I need :

1) In Crystal Reports there is an useful Field Explorer :

[image]

In Valentina for example, when the wizard asks me to add fields or group them, I get only the name of the field, without table name, it is very problematic when I have several tables, all having a "Name" field for example, I don't know which of the field "Name" I may choose.

2) Make as many groups as needed :

[image]

Also very useful if we want to make reports accessing several tables. In Valentina Reports I see possibility to add only one group (or didn't understand how to add several groups except adding SQL grouping functions.

3) Having possibility to add fields with formulas, also very useful and important point on Crystal Reports

4) (if possible) information about pricing. CR will cost 479 euro for one licence, then need to buy one licence for me, then one for each new customer(not user), Valentina Studio is 199$ for each OS(I understand that if customer has 3 licences, need to buy 3 licences).(as for example).

So I would know which alternatives can be really comparable to Crystal Reports, I mean "as good as CR", from who had experience with several softwares, because there are so many alternatives, but hard to find concrete informations on limits of each software.

**Edit** : Forgot a precision : My application is a local application, so I don't any any web service/cloud and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Is using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio out of the question ? (it's free)
Other than that check out Telerik Reporting or PowerBI.

Comment: Using Crystal Reports for Visual Studio is free if you do an application for yourself, if you plan to redistribute the application(sell it), then it is not free, you need to buy an OEM licence, it is the same as buy a licence for yourself, then buy an additive licence for each customer

Comment: Then regarding PowerBI, it seems to be a software more for web applications? My application is local (forgot to say about it in my question, just edited it).

Comment: 1) Actually Valentina Report ADK costs 199$ per OS, 399$ for 3 OS. Having that you can deploy your app royalty-free. Zero additional payments. The unlimited number of copies. You can develop a few apps.

2) OEM is applied to Valentina Report Server. Here the price is 599$ for OEM Server, which you can deploy unlimited number of copies bundled with your app. Such a server will allow 5 connections.